# JHipster and DBConfiguration

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa, spring-data, jhipster

Maybe a strange question.
I have 2 DBConnection in my registry and goes really well, connect, select, insert, update, delete.

```js
connectionONE:
  datasource:
    password: xxxx
    type: com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource
    url: jdbc:oracle:thin:@YYYY
    username: zzzzz
connectionTWO:
  datasource:
    hikari:
      auto-commit: false
      poolName: Hikari
    password: aaaaaa
    type: com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource
    url: jdbc:postgresql:bbbbbbbbbb
    username: ccccc
```

For each of them I have a @Configuration class reading the configuration properties

```js
    @Bean
    @ConfigurationProperties("connectionONE.datasource")
    public DataSourceProperties oneDataSourceProperties() {
        return new DataSourceProperties();
    }
...
```

In some case I need to unable/dismantle one of the 2 connections. So I remove it from the registry.

How can I modify my configuration class? Now I reach an Exception and the microservice doesn't start and try to catch the Exception:

```js
    @Bean
    @ConfigurationProperties("configurationONE.datasource")
    public DataSource oneDataSource() {
     DataSourceBuilder<?> dsb = null;
     try {
      dsb = oneDataSourceProperties().initializeDataSourceBuilder();
     } catch (Exception ex) {
      System.out.println("NO Configuration");
     }
     if (dsb != null)
      return dsb.build();
        return null;
    }
```

But in this manner I raise another exception, maybe caused by the `return null`:

```js
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: ExistingValue must be an instance of javax.sql.DataSource
 at org.springframework.util.Assert.isTrue(Assert.java:136)
 at org.springframework.boot.context.properties.bind.Bindable.withExistingValue(Bindable.java:161)
 at org.springframework.boot.context.properties.ConfigurationPropertiesBindingPostProcessor.bind(ConfigurationPropertiesBindingPostProcessor.java:99)
 at org.springframework.boot.context.properties.ConfigurationPropertiesBindingPostProcessor.postProcessBeforeInitialization(ConfigurationPropertiesBindingPostProcessor.java:89)
 at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.applyBeanPostProcessorsBeforeInitialization(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:414)
 at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1770)
 at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:593)
 ... 173 common frames omitted
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could define a spring profile (e.g. "db1") and annotate `oneDataSource()` bean method with `@Profile("db1")`, then activate this profile on your app command line.

Comment: Great idea. I used it and specify the Profile in all Data, Repository, Service of oneDB and I see it goes!!!